# Problems with displaying an user selection from a Combobox in a Listbox

Tags: python, combobox, tkinter, listbox

I want the follow code snippet to take the user selection from the combobox and display it in a Listbox I have set up. When I run the code, and select from the combobox, the selection is displayed in the listbox as `<tkinter.StringVar object at 0x1007ae748>` instead of the actual text.

This is the code snippet:

```
self.datesel = StringVar()
self.entry_date = ttk.Combobox(self.frame_crearorden,width = 24, textvariable = self.datesel)
self.entry_date.config(values = datescroll_list)
self.dateusersel = self.entry_date.get()
global getvalue
getvalue = self.datesel
print(getvalue)
```

This is the function I'm using to display the user selection on the listbox(by creating a dictionary with all the info to be displayed):

```
def orderZoom(self):
        nombre = contents1
        nicenum = orderResult
        email = contents2
        num = contents3
        fechacreacion1 = fechaDeCreacion
        fechaentrega = getvalue

        global ordenOrganiz
        ordenOrganiz = {"Num Orden": nicenum,
                        "Nombre": nombre, 
                        "Email": email,
                        "Num Tel/Cel": num,
                        "Orden Creada:": fechacreacion1,
                        "Fecha de Entrega": fechaentrega}
        return dict(ordenOrganiz)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling the `get` method before the user ever has a chance to select something from the menu. You need to get the value from inside `orderZoom`, after the user has been able to select something.

```
def orderZoom(self):
    ...
    fechaentrega = self.datasel.get()
```

Comment: Very nice of you to correct my rookie mistakes! Thanks!